# What does underscore cursor (caret?) and half cursor (caret?) mean?

Tags: key-bindings, vscode

I noticed different styles. But I cannot relate to what I typed, maybe because I have many missed key strokes.

Comment: We need more info to be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim!

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear? Maybe it's specific to the vscode vim extension?

Comment: @samuelnihoul It's certainly unclear to me! If you can't think of any way to describe it more precisely, perhaps a screenshot might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim allows the cursor shape to be customized. Depending on your system, Vim changes the cursor shape according to the mode it is in. By default, some of these are

- normal mode: a block cursor
- insert mode: a vertical bar
- operator pending mode: a "half cursor"
- replace mode: a horizontal bar (or "underscore")

To illustrate, Vim starts in normal mode. Hit `i`, and vim is now in insert mode. Now, any keypress gets inserted as text. Hit `<Esc>` to return to normal mode. Hit `d`, and vim is in operator pending mode, waiting for a motion to specify the text that this **d**elete operator will work on. etc.

There are other modes too, such as visual, visualLine, to name a few. For more, see

- `:help vim-modes`,
- `:help mode-switching`,
- `:help 'showmode'`.

For the vscode vim extension, the list of modes can be found [here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vim-modes).

Comment: Thanks! I meant half-block cursor (just the bottom part). Any idea?

Comment: I am using the vscode vim extension

Comment: @samuelnihoul Oh, I think that half-block cursor would be when vim is in operator-pending mode (eg. after one of `c`,`d`,`y` is pressed, and vim is waiting for a motion/text-object).  I have my edited my answer to include this detail. While I don't use the vscode vim extension, I believe this behavior work the same way in vscode vim.